# Guzzle Http not found mailgun

Tags: php, composer-php, centos7, mailgun, guzzle6

I'm trying to use Mailgun in my php project.
I've installed all the necessary components:

- Composer
- Guzzle 6

This is my PHP code to test the e-mail service:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$client = new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client();

define('MAILGUN_KEY', 'key-xxxxxxxxxx');
define('MAILGUN_DOMAIN', 'my-domain.nl');

$mailgun = new \Mailgun\Mailgun(MAILGUN_KEY, $client);

$mailgun->sendMessage(MAILGUN_DOMAIN, [
            'from'      => 'my@email.com',
            'to'        => 'your@e-mail.com',
            'subject'   => 'This is a test e-mail',
            'html'      => "
                Hello,</br></br>
                This is a test." 
        ]);
```

It still throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client' not found
```

Why is it still unable to find Guzzle6 while it is installed and required in composer.json?

EDIT:

Maybe some important information, I have installed composer and Guzzle in /usr/local/lib and made it globally available. Should i do it this way or install those in the root folder of my domain?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();`

Comment: That just returns a different error: `Fatal error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client'`instead of the other one...so no luck yet..

Comment: what do you mean by "made it globally available"?

Comment: There are multiple domains on this server. I installed the package and made it executeable for every user on the server so that i don't need to install it seperately for every domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue:

Apparently I needed to install composer and mailgun dependencies in the root folder of my domain instead of globally.

I changed the path to guzzle to this because I found this on a forum:

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

which gave me this error:

```
    Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to   Mailgun\Mailgun::__construct() must be an instance of Http\Client\HttpClient, instance of GuzzleHttp\Client
```

Which I fixed by running this command in terminal:

```
    php composer.phar require php-http/guzzle6-adapter:^1.0
```

and changing the path back to the original path:

```
    $client = new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client();
```

So now mailgun works great using this code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$client = new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client();

define('MAILGUN_KEY', 'key-xxxxxxxxxx');
define('MAILGUN_DOMAIN', 'my-domain.nl');

$mailgun = new \Mailgun\Mailgun(MAILGUN_KEY, $client);

$mailgun->sendMessage(MAILGUN_DOMAIN, [
        'from'      => 'my@email.com',
        'to'        => 'your@e-mail.com',
        'subject'   => 'This is a test e-mail',
        'html'      => "
            Hello,</br></br>
            This is a test." 
    ]);
```